# How to query entities from Azure Storage Table with AzureRM?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook, azure-rm, az

I have a couple of Azure Runbooks which use `AzureRM` to automatically scale service plans depending in some configuration.

That configuration is saved on my Azure Storage Account as entities in a table.

However, I can't find a way to read the entities from that table using `AzureRM` in my runbooks...

I can't use any `Az` modules because it would complain about also importing `AzureRM` next to `Az`. And I don't want to have 2 separate automation accounts just to be able to use `AzureRM` and `Az` at the same time.

So is there any way to get all the entities from an Azure Storage Table using the `AzureRM` module?

Comment: Could also make use of the alias option in the Az module. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/enable-azurermalias?view=azps-2.8.0 . This will allow you to use (most) AzureRM functions, while also using the Az module

Comment: @MichaelB. that seems to have fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to the comment of [Michale B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10290215/michael-b) on my question, the following has fixed my problem:

> Could also make use of the alias option in the Az module. learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/… . This will allow you to use (most) AzureRM functions, while also using the Az module

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, if you want to use `AzureRm` module to get all the entities from an Azure Storage Table, you can use the modlue `AzureRmStorageTable`. But please note that its version only lows than 1.0.0.23. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/paulomarquesc/AzureRmStorageTable/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md.

For example:

```
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$table = Get-AzureStorageTableTable -resourceGroup jimtest -tableName SchemasTable -storageAccountName jimtestdiag417
Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll -table $table
```

[image]

---

### Update

Regarding how to install the special version module for Azure Automation account, you can do that via the [page](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRmStorageTable/1.0.0.23).
[image]

Comment: I can't select a specific version because I'm using Azure Runbooks...